# How to use higher order functions instead of FOR Loop for Line items in Suitelet printouts (Netsuite)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, netsuite, higher-order-functions, suitescript

i have been tasked by my senior to print values of line items using higher order functions (`.filter/.map/.reject/.reduce`). I m confused how to write the higher order function instead of a for loop(for printing the line values in Invoice Printout). I need to print the line only when the qty is more than 3. I m an intern and i dont know how it will work, kindly help.

Link to The code snippet: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uVQQb0dsg_bo53fT3vk9f0G8WwZomgQg/view?usp=sharing

I always used if condition for printing the row only when the quantity field has value more than 3. I even know how to .filter but i dont know how to call it and where to call it. Please help

Comment: you can use for each with if condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe Array.from works in server side code. If it does then use that. What I have been using are the following functions. They don't conform to the higher order functions specified but they work with Netsuite syntax and go a long way towards simplifying sublist handling and encapsulating code:

```
//SS2.x
//I have this as a snippet that can be included in server side scripts
function iter(rec, listName, cb){
    var lim = rec.getLineCount({sublistId:listName});
    var i = 0;
    var getV = function (fld){
        return rec.getSublistValue({sublistId:listName, fieldId:fld, line:i});
    };
    for(; i< lim; i++){
        cb(i, getV);
    }
}
// to use it:
iter(ctx.newRecord, 'item', function(idx, getV){
  if(parseInt(getV('quantity')) >3){
   ...
  }
});
```

or for SS1 scripts I have the following which allows code to be shared between UserEvent and Scheduled scripts or Suitelets

```
function forRecordLines(rec, machName, op, doReverse) {
    var i, pred, incr;
    var getVal = rec ? function(fld) {
            return rec.getLineItemValue(machName, fld, i);
        } : function(fld) {
            return nlapiGetLineItemValue(machName, fld, i);
        };
    var getText = rec ? function(fld) {
            return rec.getLineItemText(machName, fld, i);
        } : function(fld) {
            return nlapiGetLineItemText(machName, fld, i);
        };
    var setVal = rec ? function(fld, val) {
            rec.setLineItemValue(machName, fld, i, val);
        } : function(fld, val) {
            nlapiSetLineItemValue(machName, fld, i, val);
        };
    var machCount = rec ? rec.getLineItemCount(machName) : nlapiGetLineItemCount(machName);

    if(!doReverse){
        i = 1;
        pred = function(){ return i<= machCount;};
        incr = function(){ i++;};
    }else{
        i = machCount;
        pred = function(){ return i>0;};
        incr = function(){ i--;};
    }

    while(pred()){
        var ret = op(i, getVal, getText, setVal);
        incr();
        if (typeof ret != 'undefined' && !ret) break;
    }

}

// User Event Script:
forRecordLines(null, 'item', function(idx, getV, getT, setV){
  if(parseInt(getV('quantity')) >3){
   ...
  } 
});

// in a Scheduled Script:
forRecordLines(nlapiLoadRecord('salesorder', id), 'item', function(idx, getV, getT, setV){
  if(parseInt(getV('quantity')) >3){
   ...
  } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually its a straight forward task, but since you are getting length and based on that you are iterating, you can use `Array.from`. Its signature is:

> Array.from(ArrayLikeObject, mapFunction);

```js
var tableData = Array.from({ length: countItem}, function(index) {
  vendorBillRec.selectLineItem('item', index);
  var item = vendorBillRec.getCurrentLineItemText('item', 'item');
  var description = nlapiEscapeXML(vendorBillRec.getCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'description'));
  var quantity = parseFloat(nullNumber(vendorBillRec.getCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'quantity')));
  return { item, description, quantity}
});

var htmlData = tableData.filter(...).map(getRowMarkup).join('');

function getRowMarkup(data) {
const { itemName, descript, quantity } = data;
return  '<tr>' +
          '<td colspan="6">' +
            '<p>' + itemName + ' ' + descript + '</p>'+
          '</td>' +
          '<td colspan="2" align="right">' + quantity + '</td>' +
        '</tr>';
}
```

---

Or if you like to use more functional approach:

- Create a function that reads and give you all data in Array format. You can use this data for any task.
- Create a function that will accept an object of specified properties and returns a markup.
- Pass the data to this markup after any filter condition.

Idea is to isolate both the task:
 - Getting data that needs to be processed
 - Presentation logic and style related code

```js
var htmlString = Array.from({ length: countItem}, function(index) {
  vendorBillRec.selectLineItem('item', index);
  var item = vendorBillRec.getCurrentLineItemText('item', 'item');
  var description = nlapiEscapeXML(vendorBillRec.getCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'description'));
  var qty = parseFloat(nullNumber(vendorBillRec.getCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'quantity')));
  return getRowMarkup(item, description, qty)
}).join('');

function getRowMarkup(itemName, descript, quantity) {
return  '<tr>' +
          '<td colspan="6">' +
            '<p>' + itemName + ' ' + descript + '</p>'+
          '</td>' +
          '<td colspan="2" align="right">' + quantity + '</td>' +
        '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: thats so simple! thanks alot Rajesh, this let me learn new way.